# Java calendar API get last millisecond of the day

Tags: java

I need to get a date in normal style but at the end to print it with the very last millisecond in the day.

for example:
10/10/2012 --> 10/10/2012 23:59:59.999999

This is my code:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(givenDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);
Date convertedDate = calendar.getTime();
```

But I get the milliseconds wrong:
10/10/2012 23:59:59:000999

Help please.

Comment: How do you create the output string from the new date?

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS  SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: Btw, you probably don't want to go the way of 'the last XXX before YYY'. This is bound to cause trouble.

Comment: You did notice that there are only 1000 *milli*seconds in a second? -> `ss.SSS` is what you need for a correct output.

Comment: How many milliseconds are in a second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A millisecond is 1/1000th of a second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), not a millionth of a second. So the answer would be right, but it seems that your millisecond field is too long.